# GIS Metadata from GIS.NYS.GOV Shapefiles does not seem to be using Lat/Lon -- Any way to convert?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I've downloaded shapefiles from NYS for use in helping us to determine attributes of various addresses. Unfortunately the shapefiles have come from various sources, and the ones from NYS I'm having trouble getting the longitudinal and latitudinal coordinates out of the vector layers in QGIS.

http://gis.ny.gov/gisdata/inventories/details.cfm?DSID=927

I've loaded the shapefile in QGIS, right-clicked on the layer, chosen "Save as...", kept the format as ESRI Shapefile, provided a filepath and changed the default CRS from "EPSG:26918 - NAD83 / UTM zone 18N" to "Default CRS:EPSG:4326 - WGS 84" which is what I see so many topics related to this problem provide as a solution.

When I reload the new shapefile in QGIS, the coordinates are still not in longitude/latitude pairs. It appears as though I might just need to choose the right CRS, of which I'm assuming I'm not.

An example PRJ file from one of the shapefile is below:

`PROJCS["NAD_1983_UTM_Zone_18N",GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1983",DATUM["D_North_American_1983",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",500000.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-75.0],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]`

Any suggestions? I haven't had to do CRS conversion on shapefiles before. I've been super lucky, I guess.

Comment: Have you tried the "reproject layer" tool? Save the output of that and see if it's not lat/lon.

Comment: It seems I may have actually been successful (previously), but the tool I was using to process the shapefiles to dynamically gather the points was failing for some reason. I don't think the "reproject layer" tool did anything different than the "Save as..." functionality, in all honesty - but your comment made me look a little further to realize my 3rd party tool may be at fault here. Sorry, but thank you! (After commenting out a line of code, it processes properly and I get the coordinate values I was looking for.)

Comment: The "Save as.." might be the same as reproject layer tool--I'm not sure, but I was thinking that it might also be the same as "define projection" instead, which would lead to the behavior you were seeing. I guess we could look in the documentation :P

Comment: Well, the essential result is that QGIS was working as expected. I actually **was** getting my longitude and latitude values. My 3rd party tool (php-shapefile) was just choking on the output from QGIS (there might be a schema issue from the output, I don't know yet), but found a workaround and the long/lat are there. I wrongly thought QGIS would show those values in the layer attributes at the vector X/Y coords. So, the "Answer" is there was never a problem to begin with! :( Since you responded, I'd be happy to mark your answer as such as thanks.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. I didn't answer the question, just poked it a bit. You understand the "answer" much better so you should post and accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process I was going through was correct. I did not completely understand the process enough to have realized that it was correct, however. QGIS doesn't seem to show the longitude/latitude values as X/Y coordinate values (like I wrongly thought it would, for some reason) upon CRS conversion. Because a 3rd party tool I was using was unable to read the exported files I also thought I did something wrong. I did not. It worked as expected.

Comment: I just heard back from the author of the 3rd party tool (having taken a look at the original shapefiles and QGIS' converted shapefiles). The issue appears to be that QGIS does not follow the ESRI standard of storing the polygons in CLOCKWISE order, but instead in counter-clockwise order. (He does mention that "SQL Simple Features" specs follow an opposite standard, so I'm not sure which is right or wrong, exactly.)